# subtracting / adding time from joda Duration

Tags: java, date, time, jodatime, duration

For instance, I know of the `.minusDays(int)` and `.plus(int)` methods in the DateTime class of joda.

But when I'm working with a joda `Duration`, with no specific point of time attached to, is there a simple and nice way to subtract or add a specific amount of time, like a day?

Something like:

```
new Duration(startTime, endTime).minusDays(2);
```

Comment: FYI, the [*Joda-Time*](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project is now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), with the team advising migration to the [*java.time*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes. See [Tutorial by Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## tl;dr

*Joda-Time* offers methods [`Duration::plus`](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/Duration.html#plus-org.joda.time.ReadableDuration-) & [`Duration::minus`](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/Duration.html#minus-org.joda.time.ReadableDuration-).

```
myDuration.minus(                // A span of time unattached to the timeline. Consists of a number of milliseconds.
    Duration.standardDays( 2 )   // Generic 24-hour days.
)
```

Better to migrate to *java.time*:

```
myDuration.minus(                // A span of time unattached to the timeline. Consists of a number of whole seconds plus a number of nanoseconds.
    Duration.ofDays( 2 )         // Generic 24-hour days.
)
```

## No such thing as *days*

> Duration(startTime, endTime).minusDays(2)

A `Duration` in Joda-Time represents a count of milliseconds. This span of time in not attached to the timeline. So there is no notion of “days”.

To quote [the documentation](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/Duration.html):

> An immutable duration specifying a length of time in milliseconds.
>
> A duration is defined by a fixed number of milliseconds. There is no concept of fields, such as days or seconds, as these fields can vary in length.

So while you cannot add/subtract *days*, you can add/subtract the number of milliseconds is the 24-hour period of a generic day, without regard to issues of the calendar and without regard to anomalies such as Daylight Saving Time (DST).

Use the [`java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/TimeUnit.html) enum to calculate that number of milliseconds.

```
long millis = TimeUnit.DAYS.toMilliseconds( 2 ) ; // 2 days of 24 hours * 60 minutes per hour * 60 seconds per minute * 1,000 milliseconds per second.

Duration twoGenericDays = Duration.millis( millis ) ;
```

The `Duration` class offers a shortcut for that work, the static method `Duration.standardDays` where “standard” means generic 24-hour chunks of time unrelated to the calendar.

```
Duration twoGenericDays = Duration.standardDays( 2 ) ;  // Two generic 24-hour days, unrelated to the calendar.
```

Add.

```
Duration d = myDuration.plus( twoGenericDays ) ;
```

Subtract.

```
Duration d = myDuration.minus( twoGenericDays ) ;
```

## java.time

The *Joda-Time* project is now in maintenance-mode, and recommends migrating to its successor, the *java.time* classes.

Same concepts as discussed above, where a [`java.time.Duration`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/Duration.html) represents a span of time unattached to the timeline. Except the resolution is finer: [nanoseconds](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nanosecond) rather than [milliseconds](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Millisecond). Technically, a `Duration` consists of (a) a number of whole seconds and (b) a count of nanoseconds making up the fractional second.

```
Duration twoGenericDays = Duration.ofDays( 2 ) ;  // Two generic days, each being a 24 hours long.
```

Add.

```
Duration d = myDuration.plus( twoGenericDays ) ;
```

Subtract.

```
Duration d = myDuration.minus( twoGenericDays ) ;
```

Like Joda-Time, the *java.time* classes are built on the [immutable objects](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immutable_object) pattern. Rather than alter (“mutate”) an object, a fresh separate object is instantiated.

---

## About *java.time*

The [*java.time*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

The [*Joda-Time*](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

To learn more, see the [*Oracle Tutorial*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

You may exchange *java.time* objects directly with your database. Use a [JDBC driver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JDBC_driver) compliant with [JDBC 4.2](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/170) or later. No need for strings, no need for `java.sql.*` classes.

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), [**Java SE 10**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_10), and later

  - Built-in.
  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.
  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Much of the java.time functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - Later versions of Android bundle implementations of the java.time classes.
  - For earlier Android (<26), the [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) (mentioned above). See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

The [**ThreeTen-Extra**](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. You may find some useful classes here such as [`Interval`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html), [`YearWeek`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html), [`YearQuarter`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearQuarter.html), and [more](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/index.html).

Answer (score 1):

Getting clever with the API calls (e.g. using [`Duration#withDurationAdded`](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/Duration.html#withDurationAdded-org.joda.time.ReadableDuration-int-)), it *appears* that you can subtract a day from a `Duration`, so long as it's a "standard" day (86,400 seconds in a day), and so long as you set the scalar operation negative.

```
new Duration(start, end).withDurationAdded(Duration.standardDays(1), -1);
```